# How can I tell if an .aspx page depends on a .dll in a VWD Studio 2010 project?

Tags: visual-web-developer-2010

I've got a bunch of .aspx pages and a .dll page in a project and I'd like to move the .aspx pages to their appropriate place in our website directory structure to make it easier to edit and update the HTML.

But I suspect some of those .aspx pages depend on the .dll

I did a search of the contents of those files for ".dll" but didn't get any hits (but I do get hits on , so the search is looking in the contents fo the files).

Answer (score 0):

in the header of the .vb file, it'll say IMPORTS

One way this is configured is to right-click the project in MS VWD 2010 editor and choose Add Reference. In my case, the dll was in the Project so I went to the Projecs tab and chose the Dll Project.